# How to make it store ecryption in database and decryption for user

Tags: javascript, php

I have main function class for encrypted and decrypted password. But here, I want to call the function in my php (now is the other php).So, the database should have crypted password but not yet. How can i get it? Its supposedly to be crypted in database and encrypted for user see it. Thank you.
Funtion that I have is :

1. EHORS_CRYPT_VAR - for encrypted password
2. EHORS_DECRYPT_VAR - for decrypted password

> PHP

```
function addEmployee() {
global $ehorsObj;
$employeeID     = (isset($_POST['employeeID']) ? $_POST['employeeID'] : '');
$employeeName   = (isset($_POST['employeeName']) ? $_POST['employeeName'] : '');
$departmentID   = (isset($_POST['departmentID']) ? $_POST['departmentID'] : '');
$positionID     = (isset($_POST['positionID']) ? $_POST['positionID'] : '');
$languageID     = (isset($_POST['languageID']) ? $_POST['languageID'] : '');
$userName       = (isset($_POST['userName']) ? $_POST['userName'] : '');
$passWord       = (isset($_POST['passWord']) ? $_POST['passWord'] : '');
$srAuthorized   = (isset($_POST['srAuthorized']) ? $_POST['srAuthorized'] : '');
$srMultiDepAuthorized = (isset($_POST['srMultiDepAuthorized']) ? $_POST['srMultiDepAuthorized'] : '');
$headOfDepartment = (isset($_POST['headOfDepartment']) ? $_POST['headOfDepartment'] : '');
$employeeID     = $_SESSION['employeeID'];  
$propertyID     = $_SESSION['propertyID'];

$Crypted = $ehorsObj->EHORS_CRYPT_VAR($passWord);
$DeCrypted = $ehorsObj->EHORS_DECRYPT_VAR($Crypted);

/* check unique */
$sqlCount   =   "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM tblHrsEmployee
                 WHERE employeeID != '" . $employeeID . "'
                 AND employeeName = '" . $employeeName . "'
                 AND departmentID = '" . $departmentID . "'
                 AND positionID = '" . $positionID . "'
                 AND languageID = '" . $languageID . "'
                 AND userName = '" . $userName . "'
                 AND passWord = '" . $passWord . "'
                 AND srAuthorized = '" . $srAuthorized . "'
                 AND srMultiDepAuthorized = '" . $srMultiDepAuthorized . "'
                 AND headOfDepartment = '". $headOfDepartment ."'";
$GetResult = $ehorsObj->FetchData($sqlCount, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);
while ($row = $GetResult->fetch()){
    $total = $row ['TOTAL'];
}
if ($total == 0){

    $employeeID = $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK("tblHrsEmployee");
    $sqlAdd     =   "INSERT INTO tblHrsEmployee
                    SET employeeID = '" . $employeeID . "',
                    employeeName = '" . $employeeName . "',
                    departmentID = '" . $departmentID . "',
                    positionID = '" . $positionID . "',
                    languageID = '" . $languageID . "',
                    userName = '" . $userName . "',
                    passWord = '" . $DeCrypted . "',
                    srAuthorized = '" . $srAuthorized . "',
                    srMultiDepAuthorized = '" . $srMultiDepAuthorized . "',
                    headOfDepartment = '". $headOfDepartment ."',
                    propertyID = '" . $propertyID . "',
                    active = 'y',                           
                    dateTimeEmployee = NOW() ";     
    $ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlAdd, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS); 
    }else{
        echo "Record already exist";  
    }}
```

> JavaScript

```
{ field: "passWord", hidden:true, title:"Password", editor: getPassword},

function getPassword(container, options) {
    $('<input data-text-field="' + options.field + '" ' +
            'class="k-input k-textbox" ' +
            'type="password" ' +
            'data-value-field="' + options.field + '" ' +
            'data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: For security, you should not use a encription on passwd which can be decripted.

Comment: A lot of noise in this question. Could you provide a *minimal* example that shows the issue you are having?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I will update it @rmccabe3701

Comment: I have update it @rmccabe3701. Anything you want to know, let me know it

Comment: Poor design. You shouldn't even run your database query unless your `$_POST` variables are set unless you want empty Strings to be stored. Hopefully, you're using AJAX. Learn, if you're not. I would use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with [DES_ENCRYPT and DES_DECRYPT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_des-decrypt) with [SHA2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2) for passwords.

Comment: Noted about that, thank you @StackSlave

Answer (score 0):

try somehing like this

Php:

```
global $ehorsObj;
$encrypted_pass = "";
$decrypted_pass = "";

$sql = "SELECT passWord FROM tblHrsEmployee WHERE employeeID = '" . $employeeID . "' ";
$data = $ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sql, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS)->fetchAll();

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $encrypted_pass = $row['passWord']."<br />\n";
}

$decrypted_pass = $ehorsObj->EHORS_DECRYPT_VAR($encrypted_pass);
```

html:

```
<input type="hidden" class="decrypted_pass" name="decrypted_pass" value="<?=$decrypted_pass?>" >
```

javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log($(".decrypted_pass").val());
    //will show decrypted pass at console.log
});
```

Comment: Where do I put the javaScript? Is it in function? Can you take a look for a second? @Teddybugs I have update some field for password above